# Error trying to freeze a Rectangle filled with a BitmapCacheBrush

Tags: wpf, freeze

I'm trying to Freeze a BitmapCacheBrush, but when I call Freeze it errors stating it can't be frozen.

What I'm trying to do is fill a Rectangle with a BitmapCacheBrush and then at some point, Freeze it so I can then animate the Rectangle and reuse the source Grid for something else (whilst animating the Rectangle).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="LISTING">
        <Grid.CacheMode>
            <BitmapCache RenderAtScale="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </Grid.CacheMode>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle1" Fill="Red" />

        <Label Content="Test" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" />
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Click="Button1_Click"/>
    </Grid>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Rectangle2" >
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <BitmapCacheBrush x:Name="BMCB" Target="{Binding ElementName=LISTING}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle> 
</Grid>
```

In my test I am trying to see if I can Freeze the BMCB BitmapCacheBrush when the button is clicked, then as a test I want to hide the button and still see the bottom rectangle intact.

I'm wanting to use BitmapCacheBrush for the performance aspect.

Is this even possible?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say No: But my only source to prove that is the Freezable [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx) in the msdn, which says:

> A Freezable can't be frozen if any of the following are true:
>
> - It has animated or data bound properties.
> - It has properties set by a dynamic resource.
> - It contains Freezable sub-objects that can't be frozen.

So i guess you can't freeze it because of your `Target="{Binding ElementName=LISTING}"` binding.

Comment: hmmm. so what alternatives do I have?

Comment: I can only guess but you could try a OneTime binding or set the Target entirely in code.

Comment: Is there maybe a hacky "reflection" way to disconnect a bitmapcachebrush from the dispatcher and force a freeze()?